# Do curvature identities determine the form of the curvature?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $\text{Riem}(g)$ be defined as the function which takes the metric and gives the $(0,4)$ Riemann tensor. We have the following implication:
\begin{equation}
R=\text{Riem}(g)\implies \begin{cases}
R_{(ab)cd}=0 \\\\
R_{ab(cd)}=0 \\\\
R_{abcd}-R_{cdab}=0 \\\\
R_{a[bcd]}=0 \\\\
R_{ab[cd;e]}=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where the final identity is to be understood as a relation involving $R$ and $g$.

**My question is if the reverse implication is true: i.e. if given an $R$ and $g$ satisfying the 5 equations on the RHS, does that imply $R=\text{Riem}(g)$? If not, what identities do we have to append to the RHS to make the reverse implication true?**

(I want to ask this question because it is similar in spirit to
\begin{equation}
\Gamma=\text{LC}(g)\Longleftrightarrow \begin{cases}
\Gamma_{[ij]}^k=0 \\\\
\nabla g=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\text{LC}(g)$ is the function that takes the metric and gives the Levi-Civita connection.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, for the obvious reason that the zero tensor satisfies all the identities you want, but is rarely the curvature tensor of any metric on $M$.
More generally, any multiple of the curvature tensor will satisfy these identities.

The first four identities are satisfied by many tensors, which are called *curvature tensors* on $M$.
They have a nice description in terms of the irreducible representations of the orthogonal group (once a Riemannian metric $g$ is fixed).
I don't know if curvature tensors satisfying the fifth identity (the *differential Bianchi identity*) have been studied in depth though.

Comment: The local question is the one which really makes sense. It was discussed in great detail in answers to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202211/equations-satisfied-by-the-riemann-curvature-tensor) MO question.